# Remove blank spaces from email and password get by EditText

Tags: java, android

```
EditText recEmail=(EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.email);
EditText recPassword=(EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.password);
String email=recEmail.getText().toString();
String password=recPassword.getText().toString();
```

The email and password contains the white spaces at start,in or end of string if tab is pressed by mistake.

I need text out of white spaces, please help if you can.

Thanks in advance....!!!

Comment: String.trim(); or String.replaceAll(" ", "");

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) is your friend.

```
String email=recEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String password=recPassword.getText().toString().trim();
```

In the future, I highly recommend checking the Java String methods in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).  It's a lifeline to getting the most out of your Java environment.

As a general rule, I would not get rid of whitespace in the text.  What if the user's password starts or ends with a space?  They will never be able to log in.  I personally think you're better off just leaving your code as is.

Answer (score 7):

This is a technically very advanced operation, but can be achieved by extreme coding precision:

mahString = mahString.[trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29);

Comment: While I love sarcasm, in this environment it would discourage newbies from asking questions.  Fear of ridicule is a big deterrent.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
email.replace(" ", "");
password.replace(" ", "");
```

to get rid of whitespace throughout the string and `email.trim` for the ends

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using String.trim()? [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) is a reference.

```
EditText recEmail=(EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.email);
EditText recPassword=(EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.password);
String email=recEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String password=recPassword.getText().toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the String methods. Try .trim() to remove white spaces from the beginning and end.

Also check android:inputType for email.

Answer (score 0):

```
    email.trim();
    password.trim();

    it remove white spaces.

    **u can also use regular expression on it for checking spaces or any specific condition**

     String string = "kumararun2008@gmail.com";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
            boolean check = matcher.find();
            String str = matcher.replaceAll("");
            System.out.println("String after removing all duplicate white spaces:" + str);
```

or

```
<EditText 
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    Thanks
```

Comment: Please learn to use the editor. Don't indent your paragraphs unless you want them to render as code.